# How to disable automatic scrolling with html5 drag&drop in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, scroll, drag-and-drop

When you use html5 drag&drop and drag element into a scrollable area, some browsers (and Chrome among those) scroll the area automatically for you, as long as you hold the mouse cursor near scrollable area's edges.

However, this auto-scroll is not configurable in any way - and as such, I have customer complaints about auto-scrolling through large area being very slow.

I implemented nice custom scrolling in pure JS, but problem is - I can't disable built-in drag&drop scrolling! And when I run my custom JS code together with built-in scrolling, it behaves quite unnaturally (custom scroll overlaps with built-in scroll).

Is there a way to disable this "feature" (in pure JS)?

Comment: See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/f7o1s36y/ - to better understand what I'm talking about. Note that I don't even need to bind any drag events for this auto-scrolling to appear (draggable="true" is enough).

Comment: I added the answer, there are few more options, check them and see if something is suitable for what you're doing.

Comment: @JosipIvic where's the answer?

Comment: @JosipIvic Echoing EliseoSoto, where is said answer?